# Branch a master repo and merge local copy

Tags: git

How does one merge a local master branch that has diverged from the master on the server with a new branch created from the current master branch on the repo?

I have been working on a local copy of a master branch and the status of the master branch is different to when I started working on the local copy. How do I merge my local copy into a fresh branch I want to create from the master branch?

I want to do this to push my local changes to the server for safety.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, start by creating a new branch at your local master:

```
git checkout master
git branch my_feature_branch
```

Then, just move your local master to the upstream master

```
git branch -f master origin/master
```

And, push your new branch up:

```
git checkout my_feature_branch
git push origin my_feature_branch
```

Comment: +1, but probably `git push origin my_feature_branch` since `git push` won't pick up new local branches IIRC.

Comment: @Kos: Good catch, I think I rediscover that every time I try push a feature branch

Comment: I dont want to update the master on the server as there are conflicts. I would rather fix the conflicts on a separate branch.

Comment: @Helium3 You're not changing the master on the server at all. You're just creating a new branch where your local master is, then moving your master branch to where the server's master is.

Comment: @Collin - Do I push the new local branch and leave the local master(stop working on it and work on the new local branch, syncing it with the server) and then just merge the branch into the server master when ready? What happens to the old local master?

Comment: Yes, oftentimes you'll work in a feature branch for a while, pull down changes from the server's master, rebase your local master onto them, then merge in your feature branch when it's ready. We nominally stick to [A Successful Git Branching Model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) where I work.